# Using python selenium driver to download pdf file

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, download

i am trying to download a pdf file('DOWNLOAD PRODUCT CATALOGUE') from the link [steel](https://sail.co.in/en/products/sail-structural-sections). using python xpath to achieve this. but getting syntax errors. tried all permutations and combinations. the code what i have tried is as follows:

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:/windows/chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    driver.get("https://sail.co.in/en/products/sail-structural-sections")
    time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
    elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()='Download Product Catalogue']//parent::div[@class='toppdf_brochure pdfbrochure']')
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can't have a series of single quotes in a string or python will treat it as several strings.  To begin troubleshooting try changing the two outermost `'` in your xpath string to `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `xpath`:

```
elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Download Product Catalogue')]")
```

Full code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:/windows/chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get("https://sail.co.in/en/products/sail-structural-sections")
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
elem =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Download Product Catalogue')]")
elem.click()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Browser Screenshot:

[image]